# How to downcase option text in a collection_select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails app, I'm trying to format a value in a select tag.

Something like

```
<%= f.collection_select(:country_id, Country.order(:name), :id, :name.to_s.downcase) %>
```

The downcase method is not having any effect. Should I be able to use it in this way? If not, what should I be doing?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a method to your model and put in a symbol for that

see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

```
class Country
  def name_to_lower
    self.name.downcase
  end
end

<%= f.collection_select(:country_id, Country.order(:name), :id, :name_to_lower) %>
```

or use select - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

```
<%= f.select(:country_id, Country.order(:name).map {|x| [x.name.downcase, x.id] } %>
```

you might want to specify a case sort if your db is case sensitive

```
<%= f.select(:country_id, Country.order("UPPER(name)").map {|x| [x.name.downcase, x.id] } %>
```